# How to describe entire matrix or Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matrix, pandas, scipy

I have a distance matrix in hand where I would like to get its max,min, mean, median, etc. values; expected describe() to do it for me, but looks like I was wrong. Both `from scipy.stats import describe` and `df.describe()` work either on columns or rows.
What might be other approaches than calling each method separately?

Comment: What @unutbu said, or also ```df.stack().describe()```.  It's a little shorter, I don't know if either way is generally superior.

Comment: Indeed I had a numpy matrix, so did this: `pd.Series(X.flatten()).describe()`

Comment: @oztalha ravel doesn't create a copy (I think flatten does), so that should be preferred.

Comment: @AndyHayden thanks. Note for others, then the solution becomes: `pd.Series(X.ravel()).describe()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the 2-D DataFrame to a 1-D Series:

```
series = pd.Series(df.values.ravel())
```

Then call `series.describe()`.

---

For example,

```
In [24]: df  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,4)))

In [25]: series = pd.Series(df.values.ravel())

In [26]: series.describe()
Out[26]: 
count    20.000000
mean      0.514002
std       0.332819
min       0.001209
25%       0.298695
50%       0.528073
75%       0.804711
max       0.973840
dtype: float64
```